# Fields limit in find method cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I am trying to give fields limit in cakephp 3 find methods. 
Here I need only image field.So I have tried below code.

```
$user=  $this->Users->find('all')
                    ->order(['created' => 'DESC'])
                    ->fields('image');
       $this->set('users', $user);
```

But this options not working here.How to add fields limit option in cakephp 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such method named `fields()`. You should refer to the docs, being it the Cookbook, or the API docs, just throwing code together usually won't get you anywhere.

Defining the fields that should be selected is being done using the `Query::select()` method, which accepts an array of column names, alias => column sets, and expression objects, like

```
->find()->select(['field_a', 'field_b', 'alias' => 'field_c', /* etc */])
```

See

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::select()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_select)**